# Unable to download file,Python xlsx File download zero bytes

Tags: python, urllib2, xlsx

**After running the code,downloaded file is 0bytes. I tried writing response too,also tried using buffer**

What am i doing wrong,what else can i try? please help

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import pandas as pd    
storePath='/home/vinaysawant/BankIFSCCodes/'
def DownloadFiles():
    # Remove the trailing / you had, as that gives a 404 page
    url='https://rbi.org.in/scripts/Bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009'

    conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = conn.read().decode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    # Select all A elements with href attributes containing URLs starting with http://
    for link in soup.select('a[href^="http://"]'):
        href = link.get('href')

        # Make sure it has one of the correct extensions
        if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.csv','.xls','.xlsx']):
            continue
        filename = href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
        print href
        print("Downloading %s to %s..." % (href, filename) )
        #urlretrieve(href, filename)
        u = urllib2.urlopen(href)
        f = open(storePath+filename, 'wb')
        meta = u.info()
        file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
        print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (filename, file_size)
        print("Done.")
        file_size_dl = 0
        block_sz = 8192
        while True:
            buffer = u.read(block_sz)
            if not buffer:
                break

            file_size_dl += len(buffer)
            f.write(buffer)
            status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
            status = status + chr(8) * (len(status) + 1)
            print status,
        f.close()

        exit(1)


DownloadFiles()
```

i also tried

```
import urllib
urllib.retreive(url)
```

> I tried using urllib2 urllib3 as well.

Comment: Have you tried to download using requests module?

Comment: Yes. i tried doing that as well

Comment: As you are a bot, I think they are using honeypot for their security. Try using proxies

Answer (score 0):

I am not good with pandas and urllib2 but since there is no answer for this question. I think the problem is you are trying to download the first url

```
url='https://rbi.org.in/scripts/Bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009
```

you define it here and doesnt change it then

```
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

after that you try to download the thing associated with the url

```
buffer = u.read(block_sz)
```

Instead of them I guess you should try to download the href
so try to change this

```
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

with that

```
 u = urllib2.urlopen(href)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that redirection to HTTPS is done via js instead of  HTTP headers, so `urllib` doesn't follow. However you could use `replace` on the links and change the protocol manually.

```
href = link.get('href').replace('http://', 'https://')
```

While that resolves the issue, it's not a bad idea to have `urlopen` in a try-except block.

```
try: 
    u = urllib2.urlopen(href)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    continue
```